# How to solve such complicated definite double integration

Tags: definite-integrals, gamma-function, density-function, gamma-distribution

I am trying to solve this double integration, but not getting it exactly.

$$P_{int} = \text{Pr}(X_{is}<X_{ie})$$

$$P_{int} = \int \int_{x_{is}<{x_{ie}}}f_{X_{ie}}(x_{ie})f_{X_{is}}(x_{is})dx_{ie}dx_{is}\tag1$$

$$P_{int} = \int_{0}^{\infty}\Gamma\left(m_i,\frac{m_i}{\sigma^2_{is}}x_{ie}\right)f_{X_{ie}}(x_{ie})dx_{ie}\tag2$$

where: $$f_{X_{is}}(x_{is}) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(m_i)}\left(\frac{m_i}{\sigma^2_{is}}\right)^{m_i}x_{is}^{m_i-1}\exp\left(-\frac{m_ix_{is}}{\sigma^2_{is}}\right)$$ and $$f_{X_{ie}}(x_{ie}) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(k_i)}(\frac{k_i}{\sigma^2_{ie}})^{k_i}x_{ie}^{k_i-1}\exp\left(-\frac{k_ix_{ie}}{\sigma^2_{ie}}\right)$$ are PDF of $X_{is},X_{ie}$ respectively. And $\Gamma(m_i,\frac{m_i}{\sigma^2_{is}}x_{ie})$ is the lower incomplete Gamma function and is defined as $$\Gamma \left(m_i,\frac{m_i}{\sigma ^2_{is}}x_{ie}\right) = \int_0^{\frac{m_ix_{ie}}{\sigma^2_{is}}}\frac{1}{\Gamma(m_i)}x^{m_i-1}\text{exp}(-x)dx$$

My doubt is how eq. $(2)$ is obtained from eq. $(1)$.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes ...you are right that they are Gamma densities. However , I had taken them as given in the research paper.

Comment: sorry misread the density equations. They are right. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are known densities: $X\sim \text{Gamma}\left(m;\frac{m}{\sigma_X^2} \right)$ and  $Y\sim \text{Gamma}\left(k;\frac{k}{\sigma_Y^2}  \right)$ where $\frac{m}{\sigma_X^2}$ is the rate parameter.

To simplify the notation I used $X,Y$ instead of your rv and eliminated some indexes not needed to understand the question.

To understand the passage simply observe that, assuming independence,

$$\mathbb{P}[X<Y]=\int_0^{\infty}f_Y(y)\left[\underbrace{\int_0^y f_X(x)dx }_{F_X(y)}  \right]dy=\int_0^{\infty}f_Y(y)F_X(y)dy$$

and $F_X(y)$, the [CDF of a gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) can be expressed in terms of the lower incomplete gamma function

---

Further details about your comment

the integral region is the following

[image]

Thus, you have to integrate the joint density $f_{XY}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ in that regiom. This can be done in two equivalent ways

$$\mathbb{P}[X<Y]=\int_0^{\infty}f_X(x)\left[\int_x^{\infty}f_Y(y)dy  \right]dx=\int_0^{\infty}f_Y(y)\left[\int_0^{y}f_X(x)dx  \right]dy$$

They chose the former.

Comment: Got it.....Thanks a lot....Can u pls specify how the limits of integration for both the integrals are chosen....

Comment: @paru : see my edits

Comment: Ok...Will check it...Thank you once again...

Comment: @paru : See also my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4229608/confirming-pdf-of-product-of-two-independent-exponential-random-variables at one of your previous question. The procedure I wrote is the same as here, thus it can be useful for you to get familiar with these double integrations